# Testing django with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a django project, defautly testing on Django only works on sql database, but I need to work on mongodb and mongoengine.
I use Django 1.9, mongoengine 0.9 cause it supports django.
I follow the docs here https://mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.0/django.html
and django docs for test https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/
The problem is how I can config the test file to tell it I want to use mongodb database. Without any setup, the test file look like this:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
from .models import User

class UserTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_create_user(self):
        self.client.post('/users/', {'first_name': 'aaa', 'last_name': 'bbb',
                         'username': 'xxx', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com'})
        ...
```

The error when run `python manage.py test` will be:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

In `settings.py`:

```
from mongoengine import connect

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    },
}

connect(
    host='mongodb://localhost/book'
)
```

Comment: See this https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/950
MongoDB is a poor choice of databases for Django

Comment: I prefer sql too, but the team works with mongo at the beginning and I join later so have no choice. Change the version seems work but raise another error, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Define custom DiscoverRunner for NoSQLTests

For example in `yourapp/tests.py`

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class NoSQLTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        pass
    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        pass
```

### 2. Define custom TestCase class for NoSQLTests.

For example in `yourapp/tests.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase

class NoSQLTestCase(TestCase):
    def _fixture_setup(self):
        pass
    def _fixture_teardown(self):
        pass
```

### 3. Change default TEST_RUNNER in your settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'yourapp.tests.NoSQLTestRunner'
```

### 4. Write tests

#### Tests that not require database:

```
class YourTest(NoSQLTestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        to_compare = 'foo'
        assumed = 'foo'
        self.assertEqual(to_compare, assumed)
```

#### Tests that require database, use mocking:

https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/mongomock.html

Step by step

1. Install mongomock `pip install mongomock`
2. Write test:

```
from mongoengine import connect, disconnect, Document, StringField

class Foo(Document):
    content = StringField()

class TestFoo(NoSQLTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost', alias='testdb')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
       disconnect(alias='testdb)

    def test_thing(self):
        foo = Foo(content='bar')
        foo.save()

        fresh_foo = Foo.objects().first()
        assert fresh_foo.content ==  'bar'
```

Comment: I used mocking for the tests, and it is working correctly, with all assertions!!

Answer (score -2):

Testing of django while using mongodb can be done by creating a custom testcase in which setUp function connects to the mongodb using mongoengine and tearDown will drop the testing database and disconnects.

```
from django.test import TestCase
import mongoengine

class MongoTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mongoengine.connection.disconnect()
        mongoengine.connect(
            host=settings.MONGO['host'],
            port=settings.MONGO['port'],
            db=settings.MONGO['db'],
            username=settings.MONGO['username'],
            password=settings.MONGO['password']
           )
        super().setUpClass()

    def tearDown(self):
        from mongoengine.connection import get_connection, disconnect
        connection = get_connection()
        connection.drop_database(settings.MONGO['db'])
        disconnect()
        super().tearDownClass()
```

Then you can use this test case in your tests. For ex assuming we have a model named 'App'

```
from models import App

class AppCreationTest(MongoTestCase):
  def test(self):
    app = App(name="first_app")
    app.save()
    assert App.objects.first().name == app.name
```

You can run these tests by `python manage.py test`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/someshchaturvedi/6424cc3633f58daeafc3676ee764caca) is a small gist for your reference